# how much battery power consumption is allowable for an iphone app?

Tags: iphone

how much battery power consumption is allowable for an iphone application ?
My application cpu activity is around 80% will they accept my application in app store 
could any please tell me about what would be acceptable  memory usage,cpu activity ,power consumption for an iphone application

Answer (score 2):

iOS App Developer library says that :

```
Apps Must Be Tuned for Performance
```

For iOS apps, performance means more than just writing fast code. It often means writing better code so that your user interface remains responsive to user input, `your app does not degrade battery life significantly`, and `your app does not impact other system resources.`

I suggest you to read this : [Performance considerations for iOS App](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/PerformanceTuning/PerformanceTuning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW1) It clearly says that Power consumption on mobile devices is always an issue.see the link for details.

Cheers!